# Remove rows from a data frame where a cell is smaller or greater than values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, operators

I would like to remove all lines from a data frame (df) where the value in column 1 is smaller or greater than xi and xf. I have the following error message. How to solve it ?

```
> df
        m.cx      m.cy s.radius.min s.radius.max
1   65.73316  25.69588    11.095535    40.696981
2  156.24181 129.77241    19.377341    33.834851
3  483.60853 155.23006     9.419478    16.288080
4  168.21591 312.73864     1.293626    10.224021
5  510.80412 354.77320     2.869728     7.532286
6  277.21467 409.62152    20.411710    28.775076
7   92.51111 495.51111     1.416217     5.048161
8  397.36817 607.47749     8.424518    18.536168
9  224.93790 623.28266     8.530353    15.266782
10 239.04444 720.13333     2.757263     4.266439
11 491.84127 758.23810     1.717259     6.194962

xi <- 100
xf <- 200

i <- 0
for(i in seq_len(ncol(df))){
  if(df[i,1] <= xi || df[i,1] >= xf){
    df <- df[-i,]
  }
}
Error in if (df[i, 1] <= xi || df[i, 1] >= xf) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
df
> df
       m.cx     m.cy s.radius.min s.radius.max
2  156.2418 129.7724    19.377341    33.834851
4  168.2159 312.7386     1.293626    10.224021
6  277.2147 409.6215    20.411710    28.775076
8  397.3682 607.4775     8.424518    18.536168
10 239.0444 720.1333     2.757263     4.266439
```

Comment: `subset(df, m.cx >= xi | m.cx <= xf)`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
        filter(m.cx > 200 | m.cx < 100)
```